# How do I transfer audiobooks from iPod Touch to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, audiobook

I have an older iPod Touch (Model MC547LL/A) with audiobooks purchased from iTunes.

The iTunes Store won't let me re-download the audiobooks and I don't have a backup.

How can I transfer the audiobooks from my iPod Touch to my iTunes library?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I'm sorry for the situation you're in, however it's really difficult to provide an answer with the info you've given.   Please see [ask] for important info and then you can [edit] your question to add the missing info.  For example, we would need to know the OS version and what you've already done to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, iTunes doesn't let you copy media from your iOS device to iTunes; likely to prevent piracy. If you have purchased the audiobooks from iTunes, you should be able to download them back. If not, which it appears you can't, you may have to contact Apple Support.

Edit:

> Apple told me that if the author has made any edits to the book, they change the serial number and they won't allow you to re-download-even though I purchased the book!

The only thing I could come up with that made any sense is that you can't update content in iTunes. Music, Books, TV Shows, etc. are usually never changed when they are published. If the author of these audiobooks made some changes to it, they would probably have to submit a new book. This happened to me once when a music artist added a few songs to their album. He created a new album and took the other one off the store.

Comment: Thank you for your response, apple told me that if the author has made any edits to the book, they change the serial number and they won't allow you to re-download-even though I purchased the book!  The tech offered me a free movie rental tho-HA!

Comment: I edited my answer to give a possible reason for this.

Comment: Then apparently apple just didn't want to give me access to the books I purchased or offer any help in restoring my purchases either.  Well, I managed to find an app that would copy my ipod to my computer, then I could add those files to my itunes-so I figured it out without apple's help-screw them!